# How to commit file in SVN using Java?

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I want to commit a file in a repository using Java Program. I am using Subversion and we use Subclipse plugin along with STS 3.4 and JDK 7. Is it possible to commit files programmatically using Java?

Comment: Why not call the svn commands from a Java program? Example : Runtime.getRuntime().exec("svn commit");

Comment: http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/wc/SVNCommitClient.html

Answer (score 3):

You can try one of the clients available like SVKit http://svnkit.com/ which provide api to talk to svn repositories.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).